# Inequality with complex numbers - I doubt my proof is correct!

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Hi fellow mathematicians! I've started learning complex numbers and I've encountered a weird inequality I have to prove :
If
$z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| \lt \frac{1}{3}$
then
$|(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3-iz| \lt \frac{3}{4}$.

My approach:

We know
$$|z_1-z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2| ~\forall~ z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C} $$
Applying to our expression using $z_1 = (\sqrt{2}-1)z^3$ and $z_2 = iz$ we get:
$$|(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3-iz| \le |(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3| + |iz|$$
Following absolute value properties we have
$|(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3| = (\sqrt{2}-1)|z|^3$
and
$|iz| = |z|$
so
$$|(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3-iz| \le (\sqrt{2}-1)|z|^3+|z|~~~(1)$$
But
$|z|<\frac{1}{3} \Rightarrow |z|^3 < \frac{1}{27}$
so
$(\sqrt{2}-1)|z|^3+|z| \lt (\sqrt{2}-1)\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{3}$.
Finally we get
$$(\sqrt{2}-1)|z|^3+|z| \lt \frac{8+\sqrt{2}}{27}~~~(2)$$
Looking at inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can conclude by the rule of translation that
$$|(\sqrt{2}-1)z^3-iz| \lt \frac{8+\sqrt{2}}{27}$$
All that's left to prove is that
$$\frac{8+\sqrt{2}}{27} \le \frac{3}{4}$$
which is true.

I really don't think this is the solution the author expected and I'm sure there is a more elegant one with something I miss.

I'm not even sure this is correct since the final inequality is way too obvious :/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks good to me. You could elaborate why the last inequality is true.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I've just checked the $\frac{8+\sqrt{2}}{27}$ thing numerically for a value of z that has $|z|=\frac{1}{3}$ and it is true. I expanded the last inequality on paper by amplifying the fractions by 4 and 7 respectively, moving the square root to one side of the inequality and transforming the other side into a square root. In the end it is true.

Comment: Try simplifying by taking $|z|$ outside expression.